# Android Kotlin: Required Context but found String

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a method that schedules a notification. Within that method, I initialize an `AlarmManager` which will allow me to receive Intents on demand. However, I get the following syntax error in my code:

> Type mismatch. Required: Context Found:    String

On the following line:

```
 var alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
```

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.notificationapp

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import java.security.AccessController.getContext
import java.util.*

// Channel

class Notification(context:Context, notificationManager: NotificationManager, title:String, description:String, date: Date) {
    // Attributes
    private lateinit var context:Context;
    private var title:String = ""
    private var description:String = ""
    private lateinit var date:Date;
    private lateinit var notificationManager:NotificationManager;

    // Initialization
    init {
        // Download the constructor parameters into the object's attributes
        this.context = context
        this.title = title
        this.description = description
        this.date = date
        this.notificationManager = notificationManager
    }

    // Method to set the notification at a specific time
    fun setNotificationAtTime(time:Date) {
        var notificationIntent = Intent(this.context, NotificationBroadcast::class.java)
        var pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context,
            0, notificationIntent, 0)

        // Initialize an AlarmManager that allows us to receive intents on demand
        var alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "com.example.notificationapp")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because you are using `ContextCompat.getSystemService` instead of `Context.getSystemService`.

So you have two options here:

1. Use `ContextCompat.getSystemService` using the right signature:

```kotlin
getSystemService(context, AlarmManager::class.java)
```

2. Use `Context.getSystemService` removing the import statement:

```kotlin
androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
```

Comment: Android and a never-ending fight with its APIs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 2024. I'm reading this official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring and I'm reproducing this code:  https://pastebin.com/DPxBguHr and Context does not longer have getSystemService() `Context.getSystemService()` does not work. So, how can I make it work now? Api 24

Answer (score 11):

add requireActivity() before the call to getSystemService()

```
val alarmManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
```

Comment: This one worked for me inside an android fragment. Thx